# Python FileNotFound error caused by Python inserting unwanted slashes in string

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, filepath, file-not-found

I am trying to save a figure from Matplotlib to a folder location on a drive and i am getting some unwanted behavior from the filepath.

This is what i have set up to run with a real string type to handle the "\" escape character.

```
save_path = r"\\nemesis\Network Planning\Team Members\Taylor\2020_04_23 - COVID Impact 
Adjustment\Test Stores\State and Region Growth - " +str(Store_ID)+ ".jpg"
print(save_path)
plt.savefig(save_path)
```

The print statement displays the correct file path string

However when i run the savefig python appears to add an extra slash next to every existing slash in the string and gives the FileNotFound error. Full error transcript below.

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\nemesis\\Network Planning\\Team Members\\Taylor\\2020_04_23 - COVID Impact Adjustment\\Test Stores\\State and Region Growth - 17062.jpg'

I am at a loss for the reasons as to why this is occurring and have tried a bunch of different string methods and none have seemed to work.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: print(repr(save_path)). Those slashes are actually there, but print() hides them.

Comment: Ah I see. Do you know why Python adding extra slashes to a raw string?

Comment: As I don't use raw strings often, I had to do a bit of research beforehand. Answer is pending.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, I'll need to explain some background on raw strings. Raw strings are just an easier way to include backslashes in a normal string without you needing to escape them. For example, defining a string that would be printed as "a\b\c" using normal string syntax, you would need to write `my_string = "a\\b\\c"`, but with raw strings, you only need to write r"a\b\c", but the resulting string is equal in both cases:

```
s = r"a\b\c"
s2 = "a\\b\\c"
s == s2 # Evaluates to True
```

When you print the string, print() excludes the extra backslashes required to recreate the string using normal syntax:

```
print(s) # -> a\b\c
```

To view a representation of the string suitable for recreating it, use `repr(s)`:

```
print(repr(s)) # -> "a\\b\\c"
```

Now for your question. The raw string you make may look like what you want when you use print(), as it excludes the extra slashes, but isn't what you want. For one thing, I don't think you meant to have two backslashes at the beginning of the path.

```
save_path = r"\\nemesis\Network Planning\..."
print(save_path) # Prints the correct path, save the extra leading backslash
print(repr(save_path)) # Reveals the normal string representation, which requires 4 backslashes to create (where there should be only two).
```

Fixing this problem is simple: represent your file path differently. Either use normal strings and escape all the backslashes manually: `"\\nemesis\\Network Planning\\Team Members\\Taylor\\2020_04_23 - COVID Impact Adjustment\\Test Stores\\State and Region Growth - " +str(Store_ID)+ ".jpg"` or just use `os.path.join("\\nemesis", "Network Planning", "Team Members", "Taylor", "2020_04_23 - COVID Impact Adjustment", "Test Stores", "State and Region Growth - "+ str(Store_ID)+ ".jpg")` to automatically join the directories with all the proper backslashes (I can't test that second one because I'm on Linux)

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks so much for the reponse.

Comment: What exactly is it doing?

Comment: save_path = os.path.join("N:\\","Team Members","Taylor","2020_04_23 - COVID Impact Adjustment","Test Stores\\")

print(repr(save_path))
'N:\\Team Members\\Taylor\\2020_04_23 - COVID Impact Adjustment\\Test Stores\\'

Comment: That looks right. Double backslashes should be fine in paths; they're the standard way to represent the character. I believe your error was due to the double backslash in the raw string.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately i still get the same the same error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'N:\\Team Members\\Taylor\\2020_04_23 - COVID Impact Adjustment\\Test Stores\\Store 17062 State and Region Growth.jpg'

Comment: Can you verify that the file exists? Post its absolute path as it displays in your file manager.

Comment: Are you talking about the .jpg file? Because that is what I am trying to create. Have i got some syntax wrong here?  Otherwise i have double checked the file path and all the directories exist

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps pyplot.savefig always expects a Unix path. Try saving the file with all forward slashes (I'd test it myself, but I'm on Linux).

Comment: Yeah got the same error again FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'N:/Team Members/Taylor/2020_04_23 - COVID Impact Adjustment/Test Stores/Store 17062 State and Region Growth.jpg'

Comment: Are you saving this onto an external drive?

Comment: Would it possibly have something to do with the "os" module interfering with path strings? Just because I saved something to a file path fine the other day and that was without importing os

Comment: Try without the colon after "N".

Comment: Yeah same error again, still including double slashes

Comment: And with forward slashes?

Comment: So I found something that works.     save_path = "\\" + "\\nemesis\\grpdata\\Network Planning\\Team Members\\Taylor\\2020_04_23 - COVID Impact Adjustment\\Test Stores\\Store " +str(Store_ID)+ " State and Region Growth.jpg"
    save_path2 = str(save_path)
    plt.savefig(save_path2)

Comment: Essentially saved the string as another file path variable and wrapped str() around it and it worked. No idea why that worked or why it was necessary but i think its fine now

Comment: Very interesting. If any of my help was useful, please consider upvoting my answer. Glad you solved the problem!